# How are repeating dependent variable in long-data format affect outcomes in mixed effects linear regression models

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, brms

My question is about the mixed effects linear regression analysis (i.e. lme4 or brms libraries in R) using long data format in R. How does brms analyze the data where the dependent variable repeats itself across the rows of a changing independent variable within the same subject?

i.e. I would like to see if blood pressure predicts body temperature.
In this design we measured blood pressure 10 times within every 30 minutes and body temperature at the end of every 30 minutes. Consequently, I’d like to see if the average blood pressure within 30 minutes predicts the consequent body temperature at the end of every 30 minutes. In a long data format, may I have the body temperature repeat itself 10 times (as many times as the blood pressure measure) to ask this question? Or do I need to average the blood pressure for each 30 minutes and then relate that to blood temperature? What is the statistical difference here?

Thank you!

Comment: Following, as I would also like to know the answer to this! It is my understanding that you would have to average the blood pressures measurements, because for a multilevel regression model, you need a level 1 outcome and your outcome, the body temperature is a level 2 outcome. But I'd like to know what others have to say, so thanks for the question!

Comment: Wouldn't you want a time series model for this? Assuming that pressure predicts temperature, values closer to the end of the 30 minutes should have more predictive power. So you'd want to model that lag.

Comment: Measurement number within each block is included in the model.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you include this and other relevant details in the question. Ideally by specifying your full model.